# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax near '' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error...but yet I cannot see any syntax that is inappropriate... any ideas?
Here's my PHP code. I know my other pages are correct as I can run all other parts of the code with no issue.

```
<?php 

// this connects To database
$hostname="";    
$username="";   
$password="";    
$dbname="";     

mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE ("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db($dbname);


$action = $_REQUEST["action"];
if ($action == 'a') {
$custFirst = null;
$custLast = null;
$custAddress = null;
$custCity = null;   
$custState = null;
$custZip = null;
$custEmail = null;
$custPhone = null;
 } else {
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
    $query = "select * from custTab where custNo = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query) 
        or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $custFirst = $row['custFirst'];  
    $custLast = $row['custLast'];  
    $custAddress = $row['custAddress'];  
    $custCity = $row['custCity'];
    $custState = $row['custState'];
    $custZip = $row['custZip'];
    $custEmail = $row['custEmail'];
    $custPhone = $row['custPhone'];
} // end if

?>
```

Comment: `echo $query;` and show us the output.

Comment: Are you sure `$_REQUEST["id"]` is even set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `quotes` around the `$id`,

```
$query = "select * from custTab where custNo = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is dangerous and wrong depending on what the `custNo` field contains:

```
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$query = "select * from custTab where custNo = $id";
```

If the id is an integer, you should use:

```
$id = (int) $_REQUEST["id"];
$query = "select * from custTab where custNo = $id";
```

Otherwise you would have to quote it and escape the variable:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["id"]);
$query = "select * from custTab where custNo = '$id'";
```

But you really should switch to PDO / mysqli and prepared statements to avoid this problem altogether.